# VS .EditorConfig file not overriding VS Options Dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2019, editorconfig

In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-styles-and-quick-actions?view=vs-2019) for the .EditorConfig files it says (my highlighting)

> EditorConfig files are associated with a codebase rather than a Visual Studio personalization account. **Settings in an EditorConfig file take precedence over options selected in the Options dialog box.** Use an EditorConfig file when you want to enforce coding styles for all contributors to your repo or project.

When I add a .EditorConfig file to the solution, it seems to take precedence the other way around?

eg. The below values in the file and the screenshot of my options, shouldn't the `.this` warnings be coming up as errors in my IDE?

```
# this. and Me. preferences
dotnet_style_qualification_for_event = true:error
dotnet_style_qualification_for_field = true:error
dotnet_style_qualification_for_method = true:error
dotnet_style_qualification_for_property = true:error
```

[image]

Edit: This is how they show in the Error List window

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`.editorconfig` *does* take precedence.

But this is not shown in Tools | Options (that still shows your profile's settings).

When you edit code you'll see the effect in the errors tool window (assuming you enable showing messages).

Comment: That's the problem, they're showing in the Error window as Warnings not Errors

Comment: @Xynos I've certainly configured items in `.editorconfig` between warning and suggestion successfully. But I've never tried as error. As formatting is not normally something that blocks compilation... But really that – how to control formatting settings – is really a different question.